# Physical interpretation of changing phase around the Higgs potential

Tags: particle-physics, mass, higgs, electroweak

**Disclaimer:** I don't know much detail about the Higgs except for a few basic points. The field can be written as

$$\phi(x) = \Phi  e^{i\Theta(x)}$$

Which I took from the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism). I think I can see how the motion in the radial direction $\Phi$ works to give mass to a field. However, I do not understand what the phase rotation $\Theta(x)$ on the complex plane does to a field.

Is there a physical interpretation for this phase rotation? What does it do in the real world rather than in this abstract mathematical space? Is there even a physical interpretation for this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think the idea of motion in this potential may be a bit misleading. The origin of the mass (or absence of mass) comes from that you can study perturbative quantum effects (there are also effects that are non-perturbative), by expanding the action around the minimum of the potential.
Moreover, since we can "only" solve around Gaussian models (which we use to establish the particle content of the theory), the first step is to expand the potential up to second-order around the minimum yielding a matrix
\begin{equation}
V^{\left(2\right)}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{\partial^{2}V}{\partial\Phi\partial\Phi} & \dfrac{\partial^{2}V}{\partial\Theta\partial\Phi}\\
\dfrac{\partial^{2}V}{\partial\Phi\partial\Theta} & \dfrac{\partial^{2}V}{\partial\Theta\partial\Theta}
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}

Such that the lagrangian becomes
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_{\text{kin}}+\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\Phi & \Theta\end{array}\right)V^{\left(2\right)}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\Phi\\
\Theta
\end{array}\right), 
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{L_{\text{kin}}}$ is the kinetic part of the Lagrangian. Can you read of the mass of the fields from these terms?

To answer your question, there is relation between the properties of the potential under transformations and the physical properties of your model. Can you see which from the previous argument? What happens to the derivatives when the potential is invariant under changes in one of the fields?

Comment: So the derivatives would be zero if the potential is invariant under changes of the fields since they do not change under transformations?

Comment: Yes. And that will lead to massless fields, while to other directions lead to massive fields. (This is a bit more complicated because depending on the coordinates since the kinetic terms may be non-trivial)

Comment: Ah. So massless fields like the photon field only rotate about the complex plane on the minimum of the potential while massive fields do not rotate but only oscillate in the radial direction?

Comment: Maybe if you think of the movement as the fluctuations around the vacuum, you can relate the mass of these fluctuations (particle types) with the frequency of the oscillations of a harmonic oscillator. From this perspective fluctuations that move around the angular direction are free (no energy required) while fluctuations around the radial direction have an energy cost. Overall I just do not know how correct this idea of movement of the fields in this potential is, and I do not think it is necessary (at least at this level).

Comment: Yes, it is correct to think of them as fluctuations, and not as actual movement/oscillations. Thanks.

Comment: A thing I forgot to mention but it is probably important.  None of this is related to the Higgs field. This is just spontaneous symmetry breaking.

Comment: Is the top of the potential the vev?

Comment: Isn't it the potential of the Higgs field? The expansion around the the minimum in radial direction, Isn't that the Higgs particle? While the angular excitations are Goldstone particles?

Comment: The minimum of the potential is the vev (whose degeneracy leads to the existence of goldstone modes).

Comment: Yes, but no. What you said is true for any complex scalar field with the right potential, so why should you give it the name Higgs? The physics being discussed here are just the spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) of the $\phi^4$ theory for a given potential. The name Higgs is attached not because the field itself is special, but because of the role it plays in your model (usually given mass to massless fermions). This SSB is not the Higgs mechanism, although the Higgs mechanism uses SSB. That is what I wanted to emphasize.